# Replicate space bar browser behaviour using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, scroll, keypress

I'm using a bit hacky solution to bottom positon a "facebook chat bar" on my page, requiring the entire page to be inside a "viewport div" with overflow hidden and scrolling. So the entire webpage is inside this div.

The problem is that this disables the spacebar - until you click inside it. I gave up my attempt on giving the #viewport element focus, as it only worked in Firefox using

```
$("#viewport").focus().blur();
```

This is how far I've come to the solution:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 32) {
    var $spaceScroll = $("#viewport").height();
    window.scrollBy($spaceScroll);
   ...then what?
  }
});
```

What's missing is to get the page to scroll down the value of $spaceScroll in pixels, but I cant find any easy way to do this except fancy smooth scrolling plugins. I want it as light as possible.

I use jQuery 1.4 and jQuery UI 1.7.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your question...

```
window.scrollTo(0, $spaceScroll);
```

Comment: scrollTo is the jQuery plugin I'd like to avoid using if possible.. I'd like to use scrollBy, but how can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Wrong.  scrollTo is a basic Javascript method.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.scrollTo

Comment: Do you understand that jQuery is just Javascript?